# AttributeError: undefined symbol when using shared library

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries

This is my first question and I might be doing something wrong.
I am trying to implement a Python application with a library already written in C.
I have created the shared library and I am using ctypes to use it in my Python script.

This is a small part of the script.

```python
from ctypes import *

KYBER_SYMBITES = 32
CRYPTO_PUBLICKEYBITES = 800
CRYPTO_SECRETKEYBITES = 1664

def key_generation():
out_lib = CDLL("./PQCgenKAT_kem.so")
out_lib.crypto_kem_keypair.restype = c_int
out_lib.crypto_kem_keypair.argtypes(POINTER(c_char_p),
                                    POINTER(c_char_p))
pk = [] * CRYPTO_PUBLICKEYBITES
sk = [] * CRYPTO_SECRETKEYBITES
ret_val = out_lib.crypto_kem_keypair(pk,sk)

couple = [] * 2
couple.insert(0,pk)
couple.insert(1,sk)

if  ret_val != 0 :
    print("ERROR")

return couple
```

But when I try to test a main file that calls this method I get this error

```
ale@ale-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/TEST$ /bin/python3 
/home/ale/Desktop/TEST/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ale/Desktop/TEST/main.py", line 4, in <module>
lista = r.key_generation()
File "/home/ale/Desktop/TEST/RING.py", line 12, in key_generation
out.crypto_kem_keypair.argtypes = [(POINTER(c_char_p),
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 387, in __getattr__
func = self.__getitem__(name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 392, in __getitem__
func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: ./PQCgenKAT_kem.so: undefined symbol: crypto_kem_keypair
```

This is my first approach to shared libraries. Can anyone help me solve this problem and figure out where am I wrong?

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please copypaste the error here _as text_ to make it more accessible for people (also better googlable, etc)? Thanks! Also, try using `nm` or similar tool to share if the shared library actually contains the symbol.

Comment: Sure! I edited the question hoping it will be clearer and more accessible. What do you mean for "nm or similar tool"?

Comment: `nm` is a program found on some UNIX systems that shows the symbol table of a shared library. The "or similar" is because your particular OS may not have `nm`. It might have `otool` or some other command for inspecting shared libraries.

Comment: Okay now is more clear. If I try the nm command on my .so file I hardly see any C library methods and it looks very strange